# How to add Arraylist items for similar rows

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a dynamic Arraylist sList of type SearchListPojo which have attributes area, location and quantity. There can be n number of items having similar area and location. I want to retrieve and add the corresponding quantity of the items having similar area and location.

My SearchListPojo :

```
public class SearchListPojo 
{
String area, location, quantity;

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public int compareTo(SearchList o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == null || !(o instanceof SearchList))
            return false;
        return ((SearchList) o).area.equals(this.area)
                && ((SearchList) o).location.equals(this.location);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchList [area=" + area + ", location=" + location + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((area == null) ? 0 : area.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((location == null) ? 0 : location.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Suppose there are 5 items:

```
 [area=Area1, location=Location1, quantity=3], 
 [area=Area1, location=Location1, quantity=7], 
 [area=Area3, location=Location2, quantity=2], 
 [area=Area3, location=Location2, quantity=22], 
 [area=Area3, location=Location1, quantity=10]
```

Then after adding quantity of similar items, the list should be:

```
[area=Area1, location=Location1, quantity=10],  
[area=Area3, location=Location2, quantity=24], 
[area=Area3, location=Location1, quantity=10]
```

How do I compare every row of the list sList and add quantity of similar items ?

Comment: what code have you tried to do this?

Comment: I haven't tried yet.. I don't know how to achieve this..

Comment: Working on an answer now, give me a few more minutes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure..

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something along the following lines.  I use a `Map` whose keys are actually a composite of the area and location.  For each unique area/location pair, I keep a running total of the quantity, and at the end I print out this information to the console.

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (SearchListPojo slp : sList) {
    String key = slp.getArea() + "-" + slp.getLocation();
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(slp.getQuantity());
    int total = countMap.get(key) != null ? countMap.get(key) : 0;
    total += quantity;

    countMap.put(key, total);
}

// this for loop iterates over the Map and prints out the quantities
// for similar items
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : countMap.entrySet()) {
    String areaName     = entry.getKey().split("-")[0];
    String locationName = entry.getKey().split("-")[1];
    Integer quantity = entry.getValue();

    System.out.print("area=" + areaName + ", ");
    System.out.print("location=" + locationName + ", ");
    System.out.print("quantity=" + quantity);
}
```

By the way, the operation you are doing is very similar to the `GROUP BY` operation which SQL can handle.  That being said, if your `SearchListPojo` objects are ultimately coming from your data layer, you would be better off doing this heavy lifting there.

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted..Thanks @TimBiegeleisen :)

Comment: Please mark as correct if it solved your problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of field Quantity to long, and if you not use multithreading try this code in service class:

```
public static HashMap <String, SearchListPojo> mapOfPojo = new HashMap<>();

public static void putForEquals(SearchListPojo pojo) {
SearchListPojo currentPojo = mapOfPojo.get(pojo.getArea() + pojo.getLocation());
if (currentPojo != null) {
    currentPojo.setQuantity(currentPojo.getQuantity() + pojo.getQuantity());
} else {
    mapOfPojo.put(pojo.getArea() + pojo.getLocation(), pojo);
}
}
```

Result test:

```
SearchListPojo slp1 = new SearchListPojo();
SearchListPojo slp2 = new SearchListPojo();
slp1.setArea("Ekb");
slp1.setLocation("Elmash");
slp1.setQuantity(500);
slp2.setArea("Ekb");
slp2.setLocation("Elmash");
slp2.setQuantity(700);

putForEquals(slp1);
putForEquals(slp2);

for (Map.Entry<String, SearchListPojo> entry : mapOfPojo.entrySet()) {
System.out.println(entry.getValue().getArea() + entry.getValue().getLocation() + entry.getValue().getQuantity());
}
```